# Java Method that returns different types of generic Lists

Tags: java, list, generics, enums

I'm currently trying to write a method that goes through a list of Ant-Objects and returns a list of `AntScouts`, that extend Ant. In general, `List<Ant>` can contain a lot of different Objects that inherit from Ant.

I also have an enum for the different kinds of ants:

```
public enum AntType {
    QUEEN,WARRIOR,GATHERER,SCOUT;

    public Class getClass(AntType type){
        return switch (type) {
            case QUEEN -> AntQueen.class;
            case WARRIOR -> AntWarrior.class;
            case GATHERER -> AntGatherer.class;
            case SCOUT -> AntScout.class;
        };
    }
}
```

This enum causes a warning:

```
Raw use of parameterized class 'Class'
```

And this is the method that currently returns a `List<Ant>`.

```
public List<Ant> getAntsType(AntType type){
    return ants.stream().filter(ant -> ant.getType() == type).toList();
}
```

How can I write the method so that it get's the `AntType` enum as argument and returns a `List<AntScout>` or `List<AntWarrior>` corresponding to the enum? I REALLY don't want to use `Class<T>` clazz as argument since that would defeat the point of the enum. (I also use that enum elsewhere, so I can't get rid of it)

How can I write the method so that it get's the AntType enum as argument and returns a List or List corresponding to the enum?

Edit: This comment probably comes closest to the desired solution:
[Java Method that returns different types of generic Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74353528/java-method-that-returns-different-types-of-generic-lists/74353687?noredirect=1#comment131265415_74353687)

Comment: The most correct answer is the one posted by Alexander Ivanchenko. You can use this approach to resolve for inner classes that belong to members of a class hierarchy. Say for example that instead of being interested in the `Ant` class hierarchy, you are interested in obtaining each of the `Ant` object builders that are an internal attribute of each class. If that is the case, you won't be able to use any of the suggestions here other than what Alexander suggested. If you would like to examine this further, you can check out [this video](https://youtu.be/QeRn-wXIGtw) on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use the Power of Polymorphism

> How can I write the method so that it get's the AntType enum as argument and returns a List or List corresponding to the enum?

You're overengineering your code for no good reason.

When you're using inheritance, your classes should be designed in a way that allow to benefit from the [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

I.e. by using super type `Ant` for all your objects and interacting with them through overridden behavior without a need to discriminate between the concrete implementations and operating via type casts.

Therefore, your method returning `List<Ant>` is quite fine.

And even if you wanted to obtain a `List<AntQueen>` or `List<AntScout>` as a result of the method execution then you would need a to use a generic type variable `T`, or rather `T extends Ant`, and that would imply that you need a mean of representing the `T`. And `enum` would not help you with this task because in Java enums **can't** be generic. You need to provide as a method argument either an instance of `T` or a `Class<T>`.

```
public <T extends Ant> List<T> getAntsByType(Class<T> tClass) {
    return ants.stream().filter(tClass::isAssignableFrom).toList();
}
```

But I would advise sticking with the initial version returning a List of super type `Ant` declaring method `getType()` which returns an instance of enum `AntType`.

```
public List<Ant> getAntsByType(AntType type) {
    return ants.stream().filter(ant -> ant.getType() == type).toList();
}
```

And as I've said, Java-enums can't be generic, there's no way to obtain `Class<T>` through it. Hence, you can remove contrived method `getClass()` from `AntType`.

```
public enum AntType {
    QUEEN, WARRIOR, GATHERER, SCOUT;
}
```

## Simulated self-type

But if you're still convinced that your application logic require the ability to generate a list of concrete type like `List<AntScout>` from a list of super type, then you can make use of a recursive type bound.

For that, you need to define the super type as `Ant<T extends Ant<T>>`.

This approach is also called a simulated self-type idiom and can be observed in the declaration of the parent type of all enums `java.lang.Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` and in some other parts of the JDK like method [`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) where `T` is defined as `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

Let's apply self-type idiom for this case.

Consider super type `Ant` defined as an interface, declaring a self-returning method (you can change into abstract class if you need to declare some skeletal implementations and common fields):

```
interface Ant<T extends Ant<T>> {
    T self();
    AntType getType();
}
```

And here's a couple of concrete classes:

```
public static class AntWarrior implements Ant<AntWarrior> {
    
    @Override
    public AntWarrior self() {
        return this;
    }
    
    @Override
    public AntType getType() {
        return AntType.WARRIOR;
    }
}

public static class AntScout implements Ant<AntScout> {
    @Override
    public AntScout self() {
        return this;
    }
    
    @Override
    public AntType getType() {
        return AntType.SCOUT;
    }
}
```

That how we can perform conversion using `self()` method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Ant<T>> List<T> getAntsByType(List<Ant<?>> ants,
                                                       AntType type) {
    return ants.stream()
        .filter(ant -> ant.getType() == type)
        .map(ant -> (T) ant.self())
        .toList();
}
```

Usage example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Ant<?>> ants = List.of(new AntWarrior(), new AntScout());

    // compiles and runs without issues
    List<AntWarrior> antWarriors = getAntsByType(ants, AntType.WARRIOR);
    System.out.println(antWarriors);

    // compiles and runs without issues
    List<AntScout> antScouts = getAntsByType(ants, AntType.SCOUT);
    System.out.println(antScouts);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[AntWarrior{}]
[AntScout{}]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/yUz)

Comment: This approach looks familiar :) +1

Comment: Ivan, I corrected the example to use `antScouts`. You're using `antWarriors` twice. But you will have to make the change on the JDoodle site.

Comment: @hfontanez Thanks, fixed. That's a byproduct of the late-night coding.

Answer (score 1):

This could be possible if `enum`s could be generic, but they can't. However, that is no big deal. Just use a final class with a bunch of `public static final` fields and a private constructor. A little verbose surely, but is as effective as an `enum`.

Also, your `getClass()` method should either be a static method with the `switch` or else be an instance method without the `switch`. The later is much better, so went that way. Further, calling it `getClass()` is not a good idea since it is unrelated with `Object.getClass()` method. So I called it `getAntTypeClass().`

And this is the result:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(AntType.QUEEN.getAntTypeClass().getName());
        System.out.println(AntType.SCOUT.getAntTypeClass().getName());
    }
}

final class AntType<T extends Ant> {
    public static final AntType<AntQueen>    QUEEN    = new AntType<>(AntQueen.class   );
    public static final AntType<AntWarrior>  WARRIOR  = new AntType<>(AntWarrior.class );
    public static final AntType<AntGatherer> GATHERER = new AntType<>(AntGatherer.class);
    public static final AntType<AntScout>    SCOUT    = new AntType<>(AntScout.class   );

    private final Class<T> antTypeClass;

    private AntType(Class<T> antTypeClass) {
        this.antTypeClass = antTypeClass;
    }

    public Class<T> getAntTypeClass() {
        return antTypeClass;
    }
}

interface Ant {}
class AntWarrior implements Ant {}
class AntGatherer implements Ant {}
class AntScout implements Ant {}
class AntQueen implements Ant {}
```

See it working [on ideone](https://ideone.com/MxhN1n).

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `AntType` enum method so that it acts as the filter in your stream. I've had to guess at the rest of the class hierarchy but this might give you a starting point.

```
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
public class Demo {
    private List<Ant> ants = List.of(
            new AntQueen(),
            new AntScout(),
            new AntGatherer(),
            new AntWarrior());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var demo = new Demo();
        System.out.println(demo.getAntsType(AntType.QUEEN));
    }

    public List<Ant> getAntsType(AntType type) {
        return ants.stream().filter(type::matches).collect(toList());
    }
}

class Ant {}
class AntQueen extends Ant {}
class AntWarrior extends Ant {}
class AntGatherer extends Ant {}
class AntScout extends Ant {}

enum AntType {
    QUEEN, WARRIOR, GATHERER, SCOUT;

    public boolean matches(Ant a) {
        return switch (this) {
            case QUEEN -> a instanceof AntQueen;
            case WARRIOR -> a instanceof AntWarrior;
            case GATHERER -> a instanceof AntGatherer;
            case SCOUT -> a instanceof AntScout;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your time.

That looks like an interesting approach but unfortunately it doesn't solve the main issue for me. I'd like to return not just a List<Ant> but a List of the specific types of ants, based on the given AntType enum. So when I call getAntsType(AntType.WARRIOR) I want to have a List<AntWarrior> returned. Same for AntScout and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

First, fix the method in your enum:

```
public enum AntType {
    QUEEN,WARRIOR,GATHERER,SCOUT;

    public Class<? extends Ant> getImplClass(){
        return switch (this) {
            case QUEEN -> AntQueen.class;
            case WARRIOR -> AntWarrior.class;
            case GATHERER -> AntGatherer.class;
            case SCOUT -> AntScout.class;
        };
    }
}
```

Since this is a non static method, you don't need to take in the type as an argument. In your example it's not clear where the list is coming from, but if I add it as an argument, it would look like this:

```
public static List<Ant> getAntsType(AntType type, List<Ant> ants){
    return ants.stream().filter(ant -> ant.getClass() == type.getImplClass()).toList();
}
```

The second way to do it would be to add a method called getType() in the Ant class which returns a type variable that is set by the constructor.

```
public class Ant {
    private AntType type;

    protected Ant(AntType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public AntType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Then you set the type in each of the subclass's constructors:

```
public class AntQueen extends Ant {
    protected AntQueen() {
        super(AntType.QUEEN);
    }
}
```

Then the filtering code looks like this:

```
public static List<Ant> getAntsType(AntType type, List<Ant> ants){
    return ants.stream().filter(ant -> ant.getType() == type).toList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer.

I actually tried your solutions before and they work but the return type of getAntsType is still List<Ant>. The problem I try to solve is that I want the return type of the method to be List<AntWarrior>, List<AntQueen> and so on. Depending on the AntType argument that's been given to the method.

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear in your question. What you're asking for is not possible since the Java compiler needs to know ahead of time what type the method will be returning. There is no way to dynamically return a different type from a method and in fact you wouldn't want it to since a main benefit of inheritance is polymorphism. May I ask why you want the return type to be dynamic? Maybe I'm still not understanding your need. You can type the return to be List<? extends Ant> but there is no way to tie it to a specific Ant instance ahead of time.

Comment: I figured it was impossible for the exact reason you mentioned. I guess I'm still too inexperienced and thought "maybe there is a way around that and my professor just didn't tell us to not confuse us" (I'm a student at a university)

I'm currently tasked with an assignment and have to implement Ants that navigate through a graph and do different things. I have an AntColony class that contains List<Ant> and has to call different methods for the different kinds of ants. Therefore I need to get List<AntScout> out of List<Ant> and so on for every type of ant.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can do it. You can do it unsafely like this:

public static <T extends Ant> List<T> getAntsType(AntType type, List<Ant> ants){
    return (List<T>) ants.stream().filter(ant -> ant.getType() == type).toList();
}

And then use it like this: 
List<AntQueen> antQueens = getAntsType(AntType.QUEEN, ants);
The issue is that there is no compile time check that what you are doing is correct. In other words you could do this and the compiler would think it is ok:
List<AntGatherer> antQueens = getAntsType(AntType.QUEEN, ants);

Comment: The main thing preventing us from making it compile safe is a limitation on enums not being able to have generic types. So if you follow Victor's solution, you could make it compile safe by passing in AntType<T>.